# How to render a large image in kivy without it looking pixilated

Tags: python, kivy

I'm trying to render pictures in my windows gui using kivy box layout i want to display the image without it taking the whole screen and still keeping its quality

I've tried taking the image original height and width then halfing it, it still looks weird.

Here is what a part of my code looks like:

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.boxlayout import MDBoxLayout
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.filechooser import FileChooserIconView
from kivymd.uix.relativelayout import MDRelativeLayout


RootLayout = MDRelativeLayout(md_bg_color=(1,1,0,1))

top_layout = MDBoxLayout(md_bg_color=(1,0,0,1), size_hint=1,.2),pos_hint={'top':1})
RootLayout.add_widget(top_layout)

left_layout = MDBoxLayout(md_bg_color=(1,.5,0,1),size_hint=(.26,.8),pos_hint={'left':1})
RootLayout.add_widget(left_layout)

middle_layout = MDBoxLayout(md_bg_color=(1,0,.5,1),size_hint=(.44,.8),pos_hint={'right':.7})
class fileExplorerKivy(FileChooserIconView):
    def on_selection(self,*args):
        img.source = args[1][0]
        img.allow_stretch=True

middle_layout.add_widget(fileExplorerKivy())
RootLayout.add_widget(middle_layout)

right_layout = MDBoxLayout(md_bg_color=(1,1,.5,1), size_hint=(.3,.8),pos_hint={'right':1})
RootLayout.add_widget(right_layout)
img = Image()
right_layout.add_widget(img)
class Explorer(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return RootLayout

Explorer().run()
```

Here is what i want it to look like:
[image: Here is what i want it to look like:]

Here is what mine looks like:
[image: Here is what mine looks like:]

Comment: Welcome to SO, please read [ask] and [mcve]. Could you update your post adding the code that generate the figure within the layout and a screenshot of your resolution problem.

Comment: @jilandercy Sure, I've added the code and some samples.

Comment: probably this: `img.texture.mag_filter = 'nearest'`. [docs](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.graphics.texture.html#kivy.graphics.texture.Texture.mag_filter). For the record, I googled practically your exact question and this info came from the first result, which was a SO link. In other words you could have just googled it or searched SO, and likely solved your problem 15 hours ago. Which means this is also a duplicate question.

Comment: Yeah, adding `img.texture.mag_filter = 'nearest'` DID NOT work @OneMadGypsy there's no difference at all

Comment: @FabianJoseph - OK. That's a shame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your code is not producing the results you want, is because you never told `Image` to use mipmaps.

This is literally all you have to do. However, the filter suggestion I made earlier should still be kept in your pocket because, even though you may think it looks clean, there are likely Moire' patterns everywhere. Both of our images are white, which makes it really hard to tell. I am unsure if Kivy automatically applies a filter, and even if it does, it might not be the one you want.

```
img = Image(mipmap=True)
```

[image]

Comment: Woah, thanks alot it worked you're a live safer @OneMadGypsy okay I'll also add the filter too.

Comment: @FabianJoseph ~ you really should read those docs and while you are at it do a little research on game textures. I've spent all day playing wii, and 5 seconds solving this problem. That's because once I decided to solve it I went straight to kivy docs for mipmaps. I did that because I know that mipmaps are how you downsize textures cleanly. Point being: the more you know about your platform the easier it is to ask yourself the proper questions and find the proper answer. In this case the "platform" isn't Kivy, It's video games. Specifically video game textures.

Comment: that's absolutely true I'll try reading thorough the documentation. Thanks for your help @OneMadGypsy